# What statistical model suits for this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification, statsmodels

I have a dataset with 6 target variables and the target variables are Boolean. The requirement is to use logistic regression to build the model. Which ML approach can be used in this situation?
Will multi-output regression work with this?

Comment: Welcome!
Please elaborate:
1. How many and what type of variables are available as explanatory variables
2. What relationships are expected between the explanatory variables and the target variables (i.e. whether linearity is a reasonable assumption)
3. More context on the goal of this model (e.g. industry, scientific, general description of the domain..)
4. Whether the 5 other targer variables should or should not be used when constructing the model for each target variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to predict using *multi-label* or *multi-output*. If you are fond of Python, and in particular sklearn, read [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).